# Number of elements in fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My Question: If we have $f:X\to Y$ an etale morphism and we assume
$X,Y$ smooth affine Varieties,
why is it true, that $|f^{-1}(y)|\leq deg(f)$ ?
Why isn´t there any point of $Y$, which has more elements in the fiber than the degree of $f$?

Comment: Shafarevich II.6.3 Theorem 3. Note that the etale condition is unnecessary; this is true for any finite map. Put another way, if $f$ is etale, then your inequality is actually an equality.

Comment: Yes, I know it is true for finite maps, but I can`t see why $f$ should be a finite map?  An etale morphism is in general not finite.

Comment: @PeterWalker What might bother you is the definition of $\deg f$ is $f$ is not finite but only quasi-finite. In general, by $\deg f$ one denotes the degree of the corresponding extension of function fields. This makes sense for etale morphisms of integral schemes $X\to Y$ as etale morphisms are dominant and quasi-finite.

Comment: @PeterWalker: you're right, I was being a bit sloppy; $f$ in general is only quasi-finte. Then one needs to argue as in Georges' answer to apply the result I quoted.

Answer (score 2):

If the  morphism of varieties $f:X\to Y$ is étale it is automatically quasi-finite.
One of the versions of Zariski's main theorem (see [our friend Akhil's notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~amathew/ZMTfull.pdf), Theorem 8.5) then implies that $f$ can be factored as $f=f'\circ j: X \stackrel {j} {\hookrightarrow}    Y' \stackrel {g} {\rightarrow} Y$ where $j$ is an open immersion and $g$ is finite.
Since you know the desired relation for the finite morphism $g$ and since $j$ is of course injective you get $$|f^{-1}(y)|\leq |g^{-1}(y)|\leq deg(g)=deg(f)$$
just as you wished.

**Remark**
It is not necessary to assume smoothness of the varieties and only quasi-finiteness [Qing Liu, Chapter 4, Proposition 3.23 (a)] is used from the étale hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

I give an hint, in the form of the following question : let $A$ and $B$ be $k$-algebras of finite type over $k$ that are domains, such that $B$ is a finite $A$-algebra of degree $d$ that is formally étale, and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$, how many primes ideals $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$ are lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ ?